# Flex 3 global exception handling

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, error-handling

I want to create some sort of global error handling in my Flex application. What is the best approach for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101532/how-to-catch-all-exceptions-in-flex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now there isn't a way to do this.  So please go vote for this feature request:
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1499

Answer (score 2):

Global error handling is now available in Flash Player 10.1 (released June 2010). For details on how to use it, see

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvents.html

Answer (score 0):

James is right... you could start by routing exceptions to one static util like below to make changes and debugging easier.

```
package 
{
    import mx.rpc.Fault;

    public class FlexException
    {
        public function FlexException()
        {
        }

        public static function faultHandler(fault:Fault):void{
            //Do stuff
        }

    }
}
```