# Catch any error in Flex app and record it

Tags: apache-flex, exception, flex3

is there any way to catch any error within Flex application and send it via let's say email or record it somehow (this emailing or recording part is not the problem, just error catching for whole application is).

This would be very useful, for fining any bugs that clients get while using app, and which they don't send in as notice.

Thanx
Ladislav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101532/how-to-catch-all-exceptions-in-flex) about how to catch exceptions in Flex. It seems to have ended on an unsure note, but at the very least you can catch all the uncaught exceptions in a top-level handler and send a notification from there.

Comment: Thanx, will take a look at it and try to incorperate into my app and see how it goes...thanx again