# Catching uncaught exceptions

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

In my workplace we are mantaining a lot of ecommerce websites, some coded better than others. On some of those, sometimes uncaught exceptions are thrown, and showed by the alertbox from the flash player debug (If you have it installed).

To rise the average user experience I'd like to report all those exceptions throught a in house tool we already have.

Is there a way to catch those exceptions?
Maybe the flash player debug exposes them to javascript, or in some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [Flex SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101532/how-to-catch-all-exceptions-in-flex), particularly its update pointing to [`uncaughtErrorEvents`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#uncaughtErrorEvents).

Essentially, no.  But eventually, yes.

Answer (score 0):

they ARE logged

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/26/debugging-flex-applications-with-mmcfg-and-flashlogtxt/
(Windows vista and 7 location is C:\users\username\mm.cfg)

But the default logs don't really give much info. However, you may be able to find more info with one of the undocument features of mmcfg: http://jpauclair.net/2010/02/10/mmcfg-treasure/