# Can I make Flash Builder break on TypeError or ReferenceError?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

Right now Flash Builder is telling me I have these errors when I'm debugging, but it won't tell me the line numbers and I can't figure out how to make it break when the errors occur. Is this possible?

Example console output:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property is_flying on entities.Bird.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you made sure that the Flash Player debugger is installed? Are you using the "debug" option to execute your SWF (as opposed to "run")?

Comment: Yes. I'm running using debug and I have the Flash Player Debugger (which doesn't even tell me about these errors). The only time it shows me the errors is in the console while running with the debug option.

Comment: Ok, so the fact that the errors show up in the console mean that Flash Builder has connected to the debug Flash Player (good sign). But it's really odd that you don't get a pop up dialog w/the same errors that you see in the console (I don't think there is a way to disable that dialog). Have you tried re-installing the debug player?   Have you tried this in another browser? For example, Chrome bundles it's own Flash Player, so if using Chrome try another browser. Or try Chrome if not. IE also has it's own plugin... Good luck!

Comment: I suppose I should add more details. It works for all other errors, just not those. Also, it's not just me, it's coworkers as well. Thanks!

Comment: IF those errors were caught somehow; such as using try/catch, it seems probably there could be a trace in the catch block and the player will not show the error dialog.

Comment: Ooh, good call @Reboog711 ... (also good call on the watch point below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on your last comment I have two suggestions:

Try adding an [uncaught exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101532/how-to-catch-all-exceptions-in-flex) to your app. In that event handler, you can print your own stack trace to see where the error is coming from.

```
private function uncaughtErrorHandler(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
{
    // note I suggested doing this, but you might also get some details
    // out of the event object that is passed to this function
    var e:Error = new Error('hi');
    trace(e.getStackTrace();
}
```

Alternatively, since one of the errors mentions the `is_flying` property, you could find all the places where that property is set and wrap that code in a `try/catch` block.

Finally, that truly is a weird scenario that you and your coworkers are experiencing. If you can identify/reproduce the problem, you may want to submit a bug to Adobe.

Comment: He could also set a WatchPoint on the variable is_Flying.  Sort of like breakpoints; but they fire whenever the variable is changed.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted it, however because it's happening in a library project that doesn't have a stage, it's not catching it, which might actually be why the debugger isn't catching a hold of it either. Thanks!

Comment: @DustinRiley That makes no sense.  All Flash projects have a stage.  If the error is thrown from a UIComponent; then the error will bubble up to the Flex Application (and the Stage above it).  If you don't have the source code to the library, it will be hard to debug errors inside, though.

Comment: The error isn't thrown from a UIComponent. Which I'm pretty sure is why it's difficult to debug. I do have all the source for the library project though.

Comment: @DustinRiley The code from the 3rd party lib is executing in the context of your application, therefore, when it runs, there is a stage. Any exceptions generated by 3rd party code should be visible to you. It makes no difference whether or not the error is thrown from a UIComponent or whatever else. Finally, you might take a look at the bottom of [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#uncaughtErrorEvents) for an example of using uncaught error handler in a Flex app (the question I linked to didn't show that).

Comment: @DustinRiley Is it possible that the 3rd party code has wrapped the offending code in a try/catch block as Reboog711 suggested above? That would explain why you don't see the pop up dialog w/the stack trace. However, that would **not** prevent you from setting a breakpoint in that code. If you know where in your code the problem gets triggered, you can try stepping into the 3rd party code w/the debugger (since you have the source).